# JS: Set cursor position at the end in contenteditable div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to set the cursor always at the end when a user types in a contenteditable div with this function:

```
function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
    el.focus();
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
        && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        range.collapse(false);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.select();
    }
}
```

I call this function within a change function on the contenteditable div like this:

```
switch (e) {
    case"keypress":
        if (0 === Ie(n)) return null;
        placeCaretAtEnd(jQuery(this));
        break;
}
```

But this causes following error in the console when I start typing:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'selectNodeContents' on 'Range':
>   parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

This is my div:

```
<div aria-describedby="placeholder-ead45" class="notranslate public-DraftEditor-content" contenteditable="true"
     role="textbox" spellcheck="false"
     style="outline: none; user-select: text; white-space: pre-wrap; overflow-wrap: break-word;">
    <div data-contents="true">
        <div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="ead45" data-offset-key="2g033-0-0">
            <div data-offset-key="2g033-0-0" class="public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr">
                <span data-offset-key="2g033-0-0"><span data-text="true">sd</span></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"I'm currently trying to set the cursor always at the end when a user types in a contenteditable div with this function:"* ...at the end of what? The text that's being typed by the user (that can't be it because that's default behavior for typing LTR languages)? Are you using a RTL language? The end of the div itself? The end of the world?

Comment: Yes, at the end of the text the user is writing!

Comment: So you are typing RTL then, like East Asian languages?

Comment: Nooo! I want to set the cursor always at the end of the typed text because sometimes the cursor is before the last letter when a user types something in. And to prevent this my plan is to set the cursor at the end on keydown.

Comment: Ok, I see...so you are experiencing an intermittent lag. Is it Firefox or IE?

Comment: Seems that this is the correct description for this. It happens in Chrome. I've don't tried other browsers yet

Comment: I cam't reproduce the behavior in Chrome...how come you have so many nested block level elements within the editable div?  https://i.ibb.co/2qJP1j7/2019-01-24-021709.jpg

Comment: You can see all block levels in my HTML code above. The first div is the contenteditable and the last one where the typed message get's entered is the span#

Comment: @zer00ne And now? No help for this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see why there is a ton of ***markup inside the `contenteditable`***. What possible purpose does that serve?

Comment: I've fixed it within the keyup function. What do you think of this way? (See in answers)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it now the dirty way. It works but I'm not sure if this is a good solution. I've added a keydown listener to my document and check within the function if my `contenteditable div` is focused. If yes, I perform a click on the input which removes the whitespace and prevents the `intermittent lag`:

```
case"keydown":
    if (jQuery('.public-DraftEditor-content').is(':focus')) {
        jQuery('.public-DraftEditor-content').click();
    }
```

> (The case is part of all key functions or click functions within a
>   switch on the input)